# Generating a sine wave

Tags: wave, sine

Hello so I thought I could use a VCO to generate a sine wave , but I didn't find anything that generates a sine wave with 500Khz. So then thought to use a microcontroller, like Atmel o Arduino, but it's really difficult to create a PWM greater than 4MHz. Anyway so now I am at a loss.

Does anyone know of any ways to make a sine wave? Please let me know what you think please.

Comment: I would imagine there are plenty of folk who know how to generate a sinewave. Colpitts oscillator, Wein bridge oscillator, phase shift oscillator etc..

Comment: Yes, agreed. If these kinds of oscillators weren't easy to build, we'd not have so many question about them! (In fact, the "Related" bar on the right of this comment field lists multiple options, the most promising seems to be a Question with the title "10 MHz Sine Wave Generator") Also, no, you don't need a PWM > 4 MHz to make a sine wave; a 500 kHz PWM and a low pass filter with a cut-off frequency anywhere between 500 kHz and 1 MHz would totally suffice.

Comment: Instead of using an oscillator or VCO, the "digital age" solution to create a 500 kHz sinewave is to use a DDS like the AD9850. See this project: http://www.vwlowen.co.uk/arduino/AD9850-waveform-generator/AD9850-waveform-generator.htm

Comment: [Amplitude stabilized colpitts oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/520724/amplitude-stabilisation-of-lc-oscillators/520726#520726) - this one runs about 2 MHz but can be reduced to 500 kHz quite easily.

Comment: [Similar colpitts oscillator](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/517675/how-does-the-colpitts-oscillator-reach-a-loop-gain-of-1/517814#517814) with more theory.

Comment: [Colpitts using an op-amp at 500 kHz](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/512516/colpitts-oscillator/512521#512521).